# what is attr_internal used for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby on rails while go through rails code I found that

```
   attr_internal :response_body
  attr_internal :action_name
  attr_internal :formats
```

what is it what does it do ? why they used attr_internal for action dispatch for response body  or action name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It declares an attribute reader and writer backed by an internally-named instance variable.

http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Module:attr_internal look into this

Look the main file for it

https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/attr_internal.rb

```
 def attr_internal_define(attr_name, type)
  internal_name = attr_internal_ivar_name(attr_name).sub(/\A@/, '')
  class_eval do # class_eval is necessary on 1.9 or else the methods a made private
    # use native attr_* methods as they are faster on some Ruby implementations
    send("attr_#{type}", internal_name)
  end
  attr_name, internal_name = "#{attr_name}=", "#{internal_name}=" if type == :writer
  alias_method attr_name, internal_name
  remove_method internal_name
end


 # use native attr_* methods as they are faster on some Ruby implementations
  send("attr_#{type}", internal_name)
```

here the tricks

Comment: can you explain me more

Answer (score 7):

It should be noticed that `Rails` offers this `attr_internal` to prevent name conflict when subclassing. So, when the `attr_internal :variable` read and write instance method are created, the latter are accessed by `@_variable`, so that when you subclass with an `attr_accessor :variable`, no name collision is possible ! See the [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#internal-attributes) for more info