# is there a way in Ruby to initialize variables which starts from *underscore* eg. _variable_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i believe Ruby supports this by default.
i need to create bunch of class variables, but don't want to override already defined variables and i don't know which of them will have been defined. 
I expect something similar to class_attribute but it should create variable which starts with underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveSupport has `attr_internal`. Here is question on it: [what is attr_internal used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585170/what-is-attr-internal-used-for)

For class attribute just use `class << self`.

For plain ruby you can use `class_attribute` to define accessors with `_` in the begin, and then add aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can begin a variable with an underscore. For example:

```
_hello = "_hello"
hello = "hello"

puts _hello
#=> "_hello"

puts hello
#=> "hello"
```

Comment: i can write class_attribute :_my_var, but i almost sure that there should be class_xxx_attribute :my_var which should do same

Comment: @user2819006 I don't quite understand.. there is not `class_xxx_attrubte :my_var`, and if there was. Why would it give you `_my_var`?

Comment: i remember that i've been reading about such method which allow to initialize such sort of variables, unfortunately i can not find this in documentation.